# Folding example from Learn Vimscript the Hard Way not working?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, folding

I'm reading [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way - Chapter 18](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/18.html), which is also about folds.

I'm surprised to see that copying the sample code

```
" Vimscript file settings ---------------------- {{{
augroup filetype_vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vim setlocal foldmethod=marker
augroup END
" }}}
```

into my `~/.vimrc`, saving it, closing it, reopening it, putting the cursor on one of those lines, and pressing <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> doesn't have any effect.

Putting it more simply, if ***I don't do do anything of what I've written above***, but I just paste the following in my `~/.vimrc`

```
" Folding ---------------------- {{{
" this should be foldable
" }}}
```

then run `:set foldmethod=marker` and then I hit <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> on the middle line, nothing happens.

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `foldenable` on? (toggle with `zi`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting the `~/.vimrc` and uncommenting it bit by bit I found out that the reason for the folding not working was that I was setting `foldminlines` to a value higher than the number of lines of the fold I was trying to close.